# geometric interpretation of "Euclidean domain"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

I cite from Wikipedia: 
    Commutative rings ⊃ integral domains ⊃ integrally closed domains ⊃ unique factorization domains ⊃ principal ideal domains ⊃ Euclidean domains ⊃ fields

All of these properties have a well-known *geometric* interpretation, except perhaps "(norm) Euclidean domain". Do you know one?

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15354/characterizations-of-ufd-and-euclidean-domain-by-ideal-theoretic-conditions

Comment: A related question: What is the geometric content of Bezout's identity?

Comment: this appears to me to be a duplicate question with a duplicate accepted answer. the paper quoted below is exactly the same as the paper quoted in the link I posted. although the answer here is more precise perhaps they should be merged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a theorem of Pierre Samuel that if $R$ is normal and of finite type over a field $k$, then the following are equivalent:

1)  The map taking $x$ to ($1$ plus the $k$-dimension of $R/(x)$) is a degree map that makes $R$ euclidean.

2)  $R$ is a PID and there exists a fractional ideal whose divisor has odd degree at infinity.

The relevant paper is from the Journal of Algebra, 1971.

Answer (score 5):

Roughly speaking near every element of the field of fractions of a norm euclidean domain you have an element of the euclidean domain. More explicitly for every $q$ in the field of fractions you have an element $m$ in the euclidean domain such that $N(q-m)<1$.

Comment: To cement this image, it helps to recall how one typically proves that the Gaussian integers form a Euclidean domain: the key is to show that the ball of radius $1$ (for the algebraic norm on $\mathbb{Q}[i]$) about any point in $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ contains a lattice point in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, since the furthest you can get from a lattice point is $\sqrt{2}/2$. This really is a thoroughgoingly geometric image, isn't it?

Comment: @ToddTrimble I get the feeling the OP was asking for "geometric" in the sense of $\operatorname{Spec}$. For instance, a reduced ring $A$ is an integral domain if and only if $\operatorname{Spec} A$ is irreducible.

Comment: @ZhenLin Actually, I also got that feeling. But Yazdegerd III's response still seems worthwhile to me.

Answer (score 3):

Although this isn't "if and only if", one property of Euclidean domains $R$ which is not true of all PID's is that the special Whitehead group $SK_1(R)$ is trivial.

This is Theorem 2.3.2 of Rosenberg's book "Algebraic K-theory and its applications".

I leave it to others to decide whether this property is geometric.

Comment: This is just a fancy way of saying that euclidean domains, well, admit an euclidean algorithm (applied to the entries of a matrix). :) I don't see any geometric content.